# Кастомный AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, android-dialog, dialog, android-alertdialog

Программа вылетает после второго нажатия кнопки "btnAdd", не могу понять в чем проблема

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

LinearLayout view;
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
ArrayList<TextView> textViews;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textViews = new ArrayList<TextView>(10);
    // создаем view из dialog.xml
    view = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater()
            .inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
}

public void onclick(View v) {
    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    adb.setTitle("Custom dialog");
    // устанавливаем ее, как содержимое тела диалога
    adb.setView(view);
    // находим TexView  для отображения кол-ва созданных TextView и времени
    TextView tvCount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvCount);
    TextView tvTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTime);
    tvTime.setText(sdf.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())));
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.btnAdd:
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            view.addView(tv,new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tv.setText("TextView " + (textViews.size()+1));
            textViews.add(tv);
            break;
        case R.id.btnRemove:
            if (textViews.size() > 0){
                TextView tv1 = textViews.get(textViews.size()-1);
                view.removeView(tv1);
                textViews.remove(tv1);
            }
            break;
    }
    tvCount.setText("Кол-во TextView = " + textViews.size());

    adb.show();
}}
```

Comment: покажите стэктрейс с ошибкой.

Comment: @UjinUkr в ответ кинул

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему удалением родительской разметки элемента. Только я не совсем понял, на каком участке кода эта родительская разметка присваивается элементу и почему программа выдает ошибку, если разметку не убрать.

```
public void onclick(View v) {
    AlertDialog.Builder adb = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    adb.setTitle("Custom dialog");
    TextView tvCount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvCount);
    TextView tvTime = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTime);

    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.btnAdd:
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            view.addView(tv, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            tv.setText("TextView " + (textViews.size()+1));
            textViews.add(tv);
            break;
        case R.id.btnRemove:
            if (textViews.size() > 0){
                TextView tv1 = textViews.get(textViews.size()-1);
                view.removeView(tv1);
                textViews.remove(tv1);
            }
            break;
    }

    if(view.getParent()!=null) 
        ((ViewGroup)view.getParent()).removeView(view); // <===== FIX

    adb.setView(view);
    tvCount.setText("Кол-во TextView = " + textViews.size());
    tvTime.setText(sdf.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())));
    adb.show();
}
```

Вот стэк трейс с ошибкой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]